# Is there a way to exclude words from a query in Searchkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, activerecord, searchkick

I would like to exlude some terms a user may enter into the search bar as they bloat the results.

For separate reasons I need the `operator: :or`, but if I have a search term like "The Beatles" it searches the whole database for "The" and "Beatles" which is way too many results. I would like to exclude "the" from any query received, so it would be as if the user had only searched "Beatles".

Maybe this isn't possilbe. Thanks for the help

I tried to add `exclude: ["the"]`, but this removed any ressults which had the term "the".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried it:

```
"The Beatles".gsub('The ', '')
```

Comment: I agree this is the easiest way to accomplish this right now with Searchkick. A slightly better form would be `gsub(/\bthe|other|words\b/i, "")` so it's case insensitive, supports multiple words, and works anywhere the words appear in the query (not just at the start).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Shah. That's a smart, clean solution. And thanks Andrew for the idea to add regex to make it case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch have great solution fro solving such questions - analyzers.

In your case you need to implement Stop analyser in your mapping. Details and docs can be found here: [Stop Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/analysis-stop-analyzer.html)